# How to handle pausing application in Android written in Kivy-Python?

Tags: android, python, user-interface, kivy

I would like to ask about how to handle pausing application in Android written in `kivy` Python. I have a simple app written in Python using `kivy`. When it is deployed to an Android device, it works fine. But if i pressed home button or if the phone sleeps, then when the app is reopened, it would still display like the last time before pausing but **not responding to any touch at all**..and after a few seconds a message shows **"Application is not responding. Do you want to close it?"**

It seems that the only thing that still works is the applied `kivy.clock.Clock.schedule_interval` function. (it can be seen by an animation)

And there is not any Error in the `log` when `deploy` and `run` using `Buildozer`. The internal seems to function normally, but it is not responding to the user.

I have tried to add :

```
class mainApp(App):    
    def build(self):
        global mainw
        mainw = mainWidget();
        return mainw
    def on_pause(self):
        print('something');
        mainw.clear_widgets();
        return True  ## Changing to False also does not solve the problem
    def on_resume(self):
        mainw.clear_widgets();
        mainw.add_widget(homeWidget());
```

*Even without this, or even with empty command inside the `on_pause` and `on_resume`, the same thing would still happened.* The `print('something')` is also does not show. **This means the function `on_pause` itself is not called**.

I also have tried to add (at the top of the `main.py`) :

```
Config.set('graphics', 'resizable', 0);
```

or

```
Config.set('graphics', 'resizable', 1);
```

Thanks.

### ----------

Here is some of the log when deploying the App :

```
[INFO]:    Recipe kivy: version "master" requested
[INFO]:    Will compile for the following archs: armeabi-v7a
[INFO]:    Found Android API target in $ANDROIDAPI
[INFO]:    Available Android APIs are (19)
[INFO]:    Requested API target 19 is available, continuing.
[INFO]:    Found NDK dir in $ANDROIDNDK
[INFO]:    Got NDK version from $ANDROIDNDKVER
[INFO]:    Using Google NDK r9c
[INFO]:    Found virtualenv at /usr/local/bin/virtualenv
[INFO]:    Found the following toolchain versions: ['4.6', '4.8', 'clang3.3']
[INFO]:    Picking the latest gcc toolchain, here 4.8
[WARNING]: Missing executable: autoconf is not installed
[WARNING]: Missing executable: automake is not installed
[WARNING]: Missing executable: libtoolize is not installed
[INFO]:    Of the existing distributions, the following meet the given requirements:
[INFO]:     myapp: includes recipes (hostpython2, sdl2_image, sdl2_mixer, sdl2_ttf, python2, numpy, sdl2, six, android, pyjnius, kivy), built for archs (armeabi-v7a)
[INFO]:    myapp has compatible recipes, using this one
```

---

The log while running the App :

```
--------- beginning of crash
--------- beginning of system
--------- beginning of main
11-01 20:59:38.574 31656 31694 I python  : Initialize Python for Android
11-01 20:59:38.574 31656 31694 I python  : Changing directory to the one provided by ANDROID_ARGUMENT
11-01 20:59:38.574 31656 31694 I python  : /data/user/0/org.test.myapp/files/app
11-01 20:59:38.574 31656 31694 I python  : Preparing to initialize python
11-01 20:59:38.574 31656 31694 I python  : crystax_python does not exist
11-01 20:59:38.581 31656 31694 I python  : Initialized python
11-01 20:59:38.581 31656 31694 I python  : AND: Init threads
11-01 20:59:38.583 31656 31694 I python  : testing python print redirection
11-01 20:59:38.584 31656 31694 I python  : Setting up python from ANDROID_PRIVATE
11-01 20:59:38.586 31656 31694 I python  : ('Android path', ['/data/user/0/org.test.myapp/files/app/lib/python27.zip', '/data/user/0/org.test.myapp/files/app/lib/python2.7/', '/data/user/0/org.test.myapp/files/app/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/', '/data/user/0/org.test.myapp/files/app/lib/python2.7/site-packages/', '/data/user/0/org.test.myapp/files/app'])
11-01 20:59:38.610 31656 31694 I python  : ('os.environ is', {'ANDROID_APP_PATH': '/data/user/0/org.test.myapp/files/app', 'ANDROID_UNPACK': '/data/user/0/org.test.myapp/files/app', 'EXTERNAL_STORAGE': '/sdcard', 'ANDROID_ENTRYPOINT': 'main.pyo', 'ANDROID_ASSETS': '/system/app', 'PYTHONPATH': '/data/user/0/org.test.myapp/files/app:/data/user/0/org.test.myapp/files/app/lib', 'PYTHONOPTIMIZE': '2', 'ANDROID_ROOT': '/system', 'SYSTEMSERVERCLASSPATH': '/system/framework/services.jar:/system/framework/ethernet-service.jar:/system/framework/wifi-service.jar', 'ANDROID_DATA': '/data', 'PYTHONHOME': '/data/user/0/org.test.myapp/files/app', 'ANDROID_ARGUMENT': '/data/user/0/org.test.myapp/files/app', 'BOOTCLASSPATH': '/system/framework/core-libart.jar:/system/framework/conscrypt.jar:/system/framework/okhttp.jar:/system/framework/core-junit.jar:/system/framework/bouncycastle.jar:/system/framework/ext.jar:/system/framework/framework.jar:/system/framework/telephony-common.jar:/system/framework/voip-common.jar:/system/framework/ims-common.jar:/system/framework/apache-xml.jar:/system/framework/org.apache.http.legacy.boot.jar:/system/framework/dolby_ds.jar:/system/framework/dolby_ds2.jar:/system/framework/mediatek-common.jar:/system/framework/mediatek-framework.jar:/system/framework/mediatek-telephony-common.jar', 'ANDROID_SOCKET_zygote_secondary': '11', 'ANDROID_PROPERTY_WORKSPACE': '9,0', 'ASEC_MOUNTPOINT': '/mnt/asec', 'PATH': '/sbin:/vendor/bin:/system/sbin:/system/bin:/system/xbin', 'ANDROID_STORAGE': '/storage', 'ANDROID_BOOTLOGO': '1', 'ANDROID_PRIVATE': '/data/user/0/org.test.myapp/files', 'PYTHON_NAME': 'python'})
11-01 20:59:38.610 31656 31694 I python  : ('Android kivy bootstrap done. __name__ is', '__main__')
11-01 20:59:38.659 31656 31694 I python  : ['/data/user/0/org.test.myapp/files/app/lib/python2.7/site-packages', '/data/user/0/org.test.myapp/files/app/lib/site-python']
11-01 20:59:38.659 31656 31694 I python  : AND: Ran string
11-01 20:59:38.659 31656 31694 I python  : Run user program, change dir and execute entrypoint
11-01 20:59:38.813 31656 31694 I python  : [**WARNING**] [Config      ] Older configuration version detected (0 instead of 20)
11-01 20:59:38.814 31656 31694 I python  : [**WARNING**] [Config      ] Upgrading configuration in progress.
11-01 20:59:38.825 31656 31694 I python  : [INFO   ] [Logger      ] Record log in /data/user/0/org.test.myapp/files/app/.kivy/logs/kivy_17-11-01_0.txt
11-01 20:59:38.826 31656 31694 I python  : [INFO   ] [Kivy        ] v1.10.1.dev0, git-Unknown, 20171013
11-01 20:59:38.826 31656 31694 I python  : [INFO   ] [Python      ] v2.7.2 (default, Oct 13 2017, 07:02:15) 
11-01 20:59:38.826 31656 31694 I python  : [GCC 4.8]
11-01 20:59:38.871 31656 31694 I python  : [INFO   ] [Factory     ] 194 symbols loaded
11-01 20:59:39.557 31656 31694 I python  : [INFO   ] [Image       ] Providers: img_tex, img_dds, img_sdl2, img_gif (img_pil, img_ffpyplayer ignored)
11-01 20:59:39.632 31656 31694 I python  : [INFO   ] [Text        ] Provider: sdl2
11-01 20:59:39.733 31656 31694 I python  : [INFO   ] [OSC         ] using <thread> for socket
11-01 20:59:39.739 31656 31694 I python  : [INFO   ] [Window      ] Provider: sdl2
11-01 20:59:39.769 31656 31694 I python  : [INFO   ] [GL          ] Using the "OpenGL ES 2" graphics system
11-01 20:59:39.770 31656 31694 I python  : [INFO   ] [GL          ] Backend used <gl>
11-01 20:59:39.771 31656 31694 I python  : [INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL version <OpenGL ES 3.1 v1.r7p0-02rel0.676427c8bf7f70ce736d81c97bd5cec8>
11-01 20:59:39.771 31656 31694 I python  : [INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL vendor <ARM>
11-01 20:59:39.772 31656 31694 I python  : [INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL renderer <Mali-T760>
11-01 20:59:39.772 31656 31694 I python  : [INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL parsed version: 3, 1
11-01 20:59:39.773 31656 31694 I python  : [INFO   ] [GL          ] Texture max size <8192>
11-01 20:59:39.773 31656 31694 I python  : [INFO   ] [GL          ] Texture max units <16>
11-01 20:59:39.842 31656 31694 I python  : [INFO   ] [Window      ] auto add sdl2 input provider
11-01 20:59:39.844 31656 31694 I python  : [INFO   ] [Window      ] virtual keyboard not allowed, single mode, not docked
11-01 20:59:40.338 31656 31694 I python  : [**WARNING**] [Base        ] Unknown <android> provider
11-01 20:59:40.338 31656 31694 I python  : [INFO   ] [Base        ] Start application main loop
11-01 20:59:40.343 31656 31694 I python  : [INFO   ] [GL          ] NPOT texture support is available
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was always use as below to run the App  :

```
mainapp = mainApp();
mainapp.run();
```

which works fine until this issue. I also checked and saw that when using `mainapp.stop()`, the App was closing and then restarting again.

---

But, I just found out that changing it to :

```
mainapp = mainApp();    
if __name__ == '__main__':
        mainapp.run();
```

**solves** the problem. The `on_pause` is now triggered on the device.

---

But what is the difference?? I would appreciate if there is a compact explanation on this. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like something that would come from a bug in the build tools. Does this happen even if you build a trivial app? And does it affect Kivy apps built by others, such as [this one](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.inclem.pyonicinterpreter3)?

Comment: When i first build using `buildozer`, i simplify / minimalize the code, also removed the `schedule_interval`. At that time, the same thing also appears. I have Flapping Henry app, this works fine in my device.

Comment: You mean this may be caused by something from the `buildozer`..?

Comment: Yes, it sounds like a problem with your local build, but I'm not sure what the issue could be.

Comment: Thanks. I have edited the question, some Warnings do appear. Some of them are : `autoconf`  and `automake` not installed, and also `Unknown <android> provider`.

Comment: I also realized that `on_pause` itself is not triggered.